# R scale() printing all data set in .Rmd file output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on some statistical data to build a prediction model. I have a data frame with around 17 columns of numerical data.

I am trying to scale the data imported in r studio from a cvs file. The problem is when I scale the data, and print the file as html, it prints whole data of about couple of thousands rows under the scale command.

Here are my lines of code. Here to correct it.

```
data1 <- data_combined %>% 
  select(-time_diff_ground_1, -time_diff_2,-timestamp_1, -timestamp_2) 

scale (data1, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

dim(data1)

head(data1)
str(data1)
summary(data1)
```

Comment: assign output of command `foo <- scale (data1, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)` to avoid printing (in other words from to prevent `scale()` from dumping its output to stdout)

Comment: Thank you very much. We can also do like:
data1 <- data_combined %>% 
  select(-time_diff_ground_1, -time_diff_2,-timestamp_1, -timestamp_2) %>% 
scale (center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
then even we don't need to assign it to other var.